# Openbox autostart won't work in lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, openbox

I try to test openbox autostart script. So first I copied the global autostart to my user directory and set/check the owner and permissions:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/xdg/openbox/autostart /home/ubuntu/.config/openbox/autostart
$ ls -la /home/ubuntu/.config/openbox/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ubuntu ubuntu   545 Nov  4 22:15 autostart
```

Next step I edited and override the autostart file:

```
#
# These things are run when an Openbox X Session is started.
# You may place a similar script in $HOME/.config/openbox/autostart
# to run user-specific things.
#

# If you want to use GNOME config tools...
#
#if test -x /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gnome-settings-daemon >/dev/null; then
#  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gnome-settings-daemon &
#elif which gnome-settings-daemon >/dev/null 2>&1; then
#  gnome-settings-daemon &
#fi

# If you want to use XFCE config tools...
#
#xfce-mcs-manager &
(sleep 10s && lxterminal) &
```

After running `openbox --reconfigure` I tried to logout or reboot but no `lxterminal` comes up after login. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps because the line that should start it is commented out?

Comment: I do not understand, which line I should uncommented?

Comment: Not exactly sure - I don't usually do scripts, I have people for that - but shouldn't the `xfce-mcs-manager` be uncommented?

Comment: I expected that `xfce-mcs-manager` and `gnome-settings-deamon` are tools which I can run if I would use the Xubuntu or Ubuntu GNOME Desktop environments. And I could find no LXDE examples which are enable one of them.

Comment: There are **two** different autostarts available in Lubuntu. They have different formats. One, the one you've shown, is the autostart that is used during a pure Openbox Session (no lxsession in effect). The Lubuntu autostart is the default when LXDE is the desktop environment. At the **user** level, the Openbox autostart goes into `~/.config/openbox`. The Lubuntu autostart goes into `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu`.

Comment: The `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autstart` works for me with the final command `@redshift -l geoclue2`. I suppose if I'm using lubuntu LXDE desktop a openbox-session is started automatically. Where are the differences? Is there a man page for configuration the `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autstart`? For example I can't run the command `@(sleep 10s && lxterminal)`.

Comment: Just guessing but have `@sleep 10s` on one line and `@lxterminal` on the next?

Comment: @DKBose, that was also my first thought but it doesn't work. The terminal starts immediately after login without waiting for 10s or 1m.

Comment: It seems `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` doesn't accept `sleep 10s` [or commands with spaces in them](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXSession#Autostarted_applications_using_lxsession). So make a small bash script, say auto-lxt, in `~/bin` with `bash -c "sleep 1m && lxterminal"` as its contents. Put `@auto-lxt` as the last line in `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`. Once you see that it works, you may then reduce the `1 min` to whatever you like.

Comment: And don't forget to make `auto-lxt` executable!

Comment: BTW it's also a possibility to call that script you mentioned from `/etc/rc.local`. With respect to my question I don't understand why can't use openbox's autostart. You told me in your first comment that the Lubuntu autostart is the default when LXDE is the desktop. At least I will accept this as the answer of my question.